# Unable to use Service account with php fpm not working

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services

With k8s secrets everything is fine, but for compliance propose I am forced to use IAM role.

I am able to load all the configs and reach aws services via php4 cli. But the same via php fpm doesn’t work. My php fpm is proxied via nginx.